# Finding the point closest to a point in another feature class and the paths between them

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shortest-path

There are two point feature classes (let's call them Sinks and Sources). Working with ArcGIS Desktop, I need to find, for each Sink, its nearest Source. Normally I'd do a spatial join, but this time I need to find the path between each Sink and its nearest Source along roads, with the path itself to become a line feature, to be used in subsequent analysis. Am I right that the Network Analyst extension is absolutely necessary for this, or are there any workarounds?

Comment: You might try geometric network (with weights) or, my preference, Python with networkx module installed.

Comment: I don't have access to the Network Analyst extension right now, so I do want to try to figure out the Python Networkx module. One problem, though, is that my points are often not exactly on the road network, but slightly offset (sometimes as much as a couple of hundred meters/yards) from the roads. Is there any way of dealing with this using the networkx module?

Comment: You need additional node on the road  use near with location and split road at these points. You might also connect origin point to it.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically (as opposed to manually in ArcGIS) find the locations for such nodes and add them?

Comment: As I said use Near tool with location